# How do I unlock all of the movies?

Tags: de-blob-2

I've just reached the end of the storyline in de Blob 2 and the list of movies I've unlocked in the extras section is incomplete - the final two are still locked. Thus far all of the level start/end movies are unlocked, so none of those are missing (each movie has unlocked after the level it is linked to was complete), but I've not even *seen* the last two yet. And my daughter is now pestering me to find them for her so that she can watch them...

I believe I got the "S" rating (the highest it seems) in all but one or two levels (which were "A" rated), I guess this could be a factor?

Or do I need to find more of the "art pad" collectable objects (although they seem to be unlocking galleries so far, and not movies)?

Comment: +1, maybe this will apply to the first game as well.

Comment: @Gnome possibly... been quite a while since I played the first I can't remember if this was an issue then? :)

Comment: I haven't been able to get all of them so far.  Then again, I hadn't completed the game until recently.

Comment: Oooo, you're right @Gnome... I'm missing one moive from the first game as well (yes, I did just boot up and check ;) - "ribbon test" - but have the rest of the movies and all cutscenes. Hadn't noticed because I wasn't being pestered at the end of the first game, probably! (Edit: and it looks like I've one silver in the first game, and so one "sublevel" that is locked. I bet that's the cause there...)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need an "S" on every level to unlock all the movies. Basicly to get an S you need to get all gold medals (painting trees, freeing graydians, destroying Ink things), all styles in the level and all the little color floating things for higher points.

Source: http://www.gamefly.com/answers/questions/view/15152-How-do-I-unlock-the-last-two-videos-in-De-Blob-2-s-extras-section